# Efficient way to import a sequence of data labeled with a parameter value

Tags: import, data

Suppose we have a number of data in `.m` format, which are labeled with the value of a parameter $c$, for example, c=0data.m, c=0.2data.m, c=0.4data.m, c=0.6data.m, c=0.8data.m, c=1data.m, ...

Now, we need to import these data and assign them to `solc0`, `solc2`, `solc4`,..., `solc10` for batch processing. I use the following `Do` loop with `ToString`:

```
Do[solc<>ToString[i] = << "C:\\Users\\c="<>ToString[i/10]<>data.m", {i, 0, 10, 2}]
```

which generates lots of errors. Can anyone point out what I overlooked? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `"` in front of `data.m`. Other than that you also have a precedence issue:

```
Do[solc <> ToString[i] = << "C:\\Users\\c=" <> ToString[i/10] <> 
     "data.m", {i, 0, 10, 2}] // Hold // FullForm
```

Notice how `Get` in the resulting expression only wraps part of the path:

```
Get["C:\\Users\\c="]
```

Try writing out `Get` explicitly instead.

```
Get["C:\\Users\\c=" <> ToString[i/10] <> "data.m"]
```

But there is at least one more problem, on the left hand-side:

```
solc<>ToString[i] =
```

The left hand-side is supposed to be a variable that you can assign to, but in your case it seems to be a string. I would recommend retrieving the result of `Get`ting the files by using `Table` instead of `Do`.

Comment: Hi, thank you! According to your suggestions, I tried `Table[ToExpression["solc" <>ToString[i]]=Get["C:\\Users\\c="<>ToString[i/10] <> "data.m"], {i, 0, 10, 2}]` but still got errors.

Comment: Notice, also, the output of `ToString[2/10]`, for example. What do you think you can you do to fix this, @jsxs?

Comment: Thank you @CATrevillian noted that issue, I replaced `ToString[i/10]` with `ToString[N[i/10]]`, whereas the new issue is related with integer value of the parameter, e.g. `ToString[N[0/10]]` yields `0.` instead of `0` and `ToString[N[10/10]]` yields `1.` instead of `1`.

Comment: Indeed! Then, as I see it, you are left with two options: 1) you use this newly updated scheme to export again the files you wish to expediently import, or 2) you preconstruct the list of values which will be those numeric values which you require. Essentially you end up with something like `...{i, {0, .2, ..., 1}}]`.